Only local connections are allowed - Browser does not launch - Chrome Driver Issue
When I run my script I get the below error and Browser does not launch.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 123.0.6312.123 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Currently the latest available ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90.
How to get the issue sorted as my scripts are failing.
Tried to use latest version of chrome ; ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 - still same issue persist
Tried to use latest version of eclipse

See this answer about checking that the version numbers of Chrome and chromedriver match.

The latest version of ChromeDriver is 123.x.y.z - see https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/. That page can be reached from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ - see "Latest ChromeDriver Binaries".
So, you need to update.
